# Select2 remote data results not reloading fast enough, always 1+ characters behind [Aurelia, TypeScript, Swagger]

Tags: typescript, swagger, jquery-select2, aurelia

I'm using Select2 (ver 4.0.6-rc.1)'s remote data option to load results from a Swagger API call. I could not find much documentation on loading server-side data so that may be the problem as I am using a bit of a workaround. The dropdown doesn't load the most recent `param.term` result.

Basically only using Aurelia-specific functionality where I reference the `<select>`.

HTML:

```
<select class="select2" ref="referenceToHTMLSelect2"></select>
```

Code:

```
optionsInSelect2Format = { text: string, id: string }[];
theSelect2: any;
variableId: string;
variableName: string;

public initializeSelect2() {
    this.theSelect2 = $(this.referenceToHTMLSelect2).select2({
        placeholder: 'Select',
        width: '100%',
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        language: {
            inputTooShort: () => {
                return 'Enter at least 1 character to search'
            }
        },
        ajax: {
            url: (params) => {
                this.apiCall(params.term, "hardCodedStringNeededToExecuteAPICall");
            },
            processResults: (params) => {
                return {
                    results: this.optionsInSelect2Format
                }
            }
        }
    });
    this.theSelect2.on('select2:select', (e) => {
        let data = this.theSelect2.select2('data')[0];
        this.variableId = data.id;
        this.variableName = data.text;

    });
}
```

API call:

```
public apiCall (searchTerm: string, type: string) {
    return this.service.search(seachTerm, type)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const rawJSON = response.result;
                    this.optionsInSelect2Format = [];
                    //Lodash ForEach
                    _.forEach(rawJSON, (entry) => {
                        this.optionsInSelect2Format.push({
                            text: entry.entryName,
                            id: entry.entryID
                        });
                    });
                    return this.optionsInSelect2Format;
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Error message
        });
```

The API call is fired every time the user keys an input but the reloading of the dropdown doesn't reliably happen. The dropdown seems to reload after the first or second characters are typed, and the data it loads into the dropdown lags behind the actual param.term. E.g. user types in "i" and nothing is loaded, user follows "i" with "t" and instead of "it" results being loaded into the dropdown, the "i" results are loaded.

I do see that the `optionsInSelect2Format` array has been updated to "it" results. Is this an async issue?

GIF of the behavior:

[Select2 does not repopulate the dropdown fast enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKhiN.gif)

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding of Select2, the `ajax.url` is expected to return a url that select2 will call, the results of which are then passed into `processResults`.

Instead of returning a url to select2, you're calling the API directly yourself and returning the results from it. I don't believe that `url` function is actually awaited, so here's (probably) what happens:

1. Select2 calls `url` to get the url, your `this.apiCall` is invoked
2. With the result from `url` (which is undefined), select2 tries to make a call and can't - so I'm guessing it doesn't do anything
3. `processResults` is immediately invoked synchronously (while your `apiCall` is still executing) and `this.optionsInSelect2Format` is simply not updated yet.

You should either completely let select2 handle the api call for you (actually give it a url and process the data accordingly), or you should completely handle it yourself.

In the latter case, you may be able to subscribe to `change.select2` event (not sure if that triggers when the users types something) and on that event call a single method that calls your api, waits for the data to be returned, and then sets the new data source. Use the `data` property instead of the `ajax` property.

It *might* work if you simply keep your code as it is and set the `data` property to `this.optionsInSelect2Format` but you'd have to try that.